# How can we get a list of failed dataproc jobs and their start time using gcloud or python

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

How can we get a list of failed dataproc jobs and their start time using gcloud or python? I don't see much info about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It's tricky to do exactly what you are asking for, but this command almost matches it:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs list --filter="status.state=INACTIVE" --format="table(jobUuid,status.state,statusHistory[0].stateStartTime)"
```

This will print out the Job UUID, final state, and start time for all jobs that are no longer running.

Where this falls short of what you asked is that the returned list includes all of failed, cancelled, and done jobs, rather than *just* the failed jobs.

The issue is that Dataproc jobs list API supports filtering on job state, but only on the broad categories of "ACTIVE" or "INACTIVE". The "INACTIVE" category includes jobs with a state of "ERROR", but also includes "DONE" and "CANCELLED".

The simplest way I could get to a full solution to what you asked is to pipe the output of that command through `grep`

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs list --filter="status.state=INACTIVE" --format="table(jobUuid,status.state,statusHistory[0].stateStartTime)" | grep ERROR
```

That will only list the failed jobs, but it is Unix specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot as the command is working perfectly. However it's not listing all the jobs but only a few of them. How can I print all the failed jobs and if there is some sort of pagination that needs to applied to list all jobs?

Comment: @VinayakPandey pagination should already be taken care of in that command. If you are not seeing all of your jobs, then the most likely cause is that some of your jobs are in different regions. The command above uses the default "global" region. To list jobs for a different region, add the "--region=..." flag. For example, to list the failed jobs for the "us-west1" region, you would add the flag "--region=us-west1" to the `gcloud dataproc jobs list ...` command.

Comment: @Omar Jarjur.. how to get the list of failed jobs for current day and last day.. or may between two dates